# Why does my execve() only works when arguments include /bin/?

Tags: c, linux, shell, environment-variables

`execve()` only works when `/bin/` is a prefix to the first argument

e.g. `./test.out ls` finds nothing while `./test.out /bin/ls` works

execve(argv[1], args, getenv("PATH"))

Comment: I think you are looking for `execvpe()`.

Comment: Do you have a file called `ls`?

Comment: Regarding my earlier comment, note that `execvpe` is a GNU extension, not defined by POSIX. I'm not sure if it uses the `PATH` from the current environment or the `PATH` from the parameter specified environment.

Answer (score 3):

`execve()` doesn't search `PATH` for the executable. You have to use `execvp()` for that. The `p` in the name stands for `PATH`.

Comment: Or `execvpe`, if you also want to set the environment.

Comment: @user253751 True, but I think the OP thought passing `PATH` was the way to get this behavior, it wasn't something he really needed.

Comment: I'm not sure if OP thought passing `PATH` was the way to go, or if they just wanted to strip the environment.

Comment: Well, since `execvpe` is not POSIX, I'm not going to recommend it. The comments are good enough.

Answer (score 0):

`execve` does not search the `PATH` directories. The first parameter needs to refer to an actual file reachable from the current directory, so needs to contain `/` characters if the file is not in the current directory.

Linux supports `execvpe` as a GNU extension which is a cross between the `execve` and `execvp` POSIX functions. The `p` means it will search the `PATH` for the file as long as it contains no `/` characters.  (If it does contain `/` characters, it will the same as the non-`p` version.) The `e` means that a new environment is passed to the function in the third parameter.

OP's code passes an environment to the `execve` function that contains only the `PATH` environment variable from the original environment. If that is the intention, the same effect can be performed in a POSIX compliant manner by stripping the environment before calling `execvp`. This makes use of the `extern char **environ;` variable declared by `#include <unistd.h>`:

```
char *env_p = getenv("PATH");
char *args[] = {argv[1], argv[2], NULL};

if (environ[0]) {
    environ[0] = env_p;
    environ[1] = NULL;
}

if (execvp(argv[1], args) < 0) {
    perror("execvp");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}
```